# How to access Http feed from Https site

Tags: https

I have one website which is on https and I want to access RSS feeds from third party http website. However, it is not working. It gives following error:

> Blocked loading mixed active content
>   “http://hub.moderalofts.com/hubsFront/embed_collection”

Anyone has idea how to resolve it?

Comment: You could relay that rss feed via your own https server.

Comment: can you please guide me how to do that?

Comment: Well, either use the web servers proxying features (for example the proxy module in case of an apache http server) to republish that feed via your server or you create a relay script on that server which fetches the feed in background and forwards the response to the client.

Comment: Oh, and a warning: when implementing that do not try to be smart and create a generic proxy where the client says which URL should be fetched somehow. That would turn your http server into a proxy zombie. Only ever implement a specific proxy target.